# How to add one column data to another table column using joins or any other method?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

There are two tables one is `COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE` and another one is `COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE1`, `COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE` contain only 2 columns one is `claim_id` and another one is `NOTE_MEMO_CARETECH`. and other table have many columns but `NOTE_MEMO_CARETECH` column is missing. I want to create `NOTE_MEMO_CARETECH` column in `COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE1` with all the values which is in another table `COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE`.

How to do it?

I tried this below code but both not working.

1. ```
   INSERT INTO COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE1 (CLAIM_ID,NOTE_MEMO_CARETECH)  
   SELECT DISTINCT COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE1.CLAIM_ID,COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE1.NOTE_MEMO_CARETECH
   FROM COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE src 
   inner JOIN COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE1
   ON (COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE.CLAIM_ID=COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE1.CLAIM_ID)
   ```
2. ```
   insert into 
   COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE1 values (NOTE_MEMO_CARETECH)
   INNER JOIN COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE ON
   COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE1.CLAIM_ID = COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE.CLAIM_ID
   ORDER BY
   EVENT_ID DESC;
   ```
3. ```
   UPDATE
   (
     SELECT     
             NOTE_MEMO_CARETECH_OLD   
     FROM       COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE1 
     INNER JOIN COPYCLAIMPRGNOTE 
     ON         CLAIM_ID = CLAIM_ID
   )   
   SET NOTE_MEMO_CARETECH_OLD = NOTE_MEMO_CARETECH
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Two steps, because the target table doesn't even contain that column. DML can't create it, so you'll need DDL. Datatype should match the source table column's datatype (just as an example, I used `varchar2(20)`):

```
alter table copyclaimprgnote1 add note_memo_caretech varchar2(20);
```

The second step is the *update* (or merge, as in this example):

```
merge into copyclaimprgnote1 a
using copyclaimprgnote b
on (a.claim_id = b.claim_id)
when matched then update set
  a.note_memo_caretech = b.note_memo_caretech;
```